# Inserting In a Doubly LinkedList

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to insert into a doubly linked list. I am then trying to print the list in both forward and reverse direction. I have created a head node and I am trying to insert another one, but I am unable to do so. The program shows a runtime error.
Please find my code below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include<stddef.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};
void insertAfter(struct node *node, int new_data){
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        printf("the given previous node cannot be NULL");
        return;
    }
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data = new_data;
    node->next = new_node;
    new_node->prev = node;
    new_node->next - node->next;
    if(new_node->next!=NULL)
        new_node->next->prev = new_node;
}
void printlist(struct node *node){
    struct node *last;
    printf("Traversal in forward direction\n");
    while(node!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n",node->data);
        last = node;
        node=node->next;
    }
    printf("Traversal in backward direction\n");
    while(last!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n",last->data);
        last=last->prev;
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
    head->data = 5;
    tail->data = 10;
    head->next = tail;
    head->prev = NULL;
    tail->next = NULL;
    insertAfter(head, 8);

    printf("\n Created DLL is: ");
    printlist(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include the error in your question.

Comment: You are not allocating memory for your node pointers `*head` `*tail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here.

First, as pointed out by @Igor, you are not allocating any memory for your head and tail nodes.  You should also set `tail->prev = head`.

Second, the order in which `insertAfter` sets the link pointers causes `node->next` to be overwritten before it is used in setting `new_node->next`.  This causes `new_node->next` to point back to `new_node` instead of to whatever was following `node`.  You should set `new_node->next` and `new_node->prev` before you modify `node`.  It also appears that you have used a minus sign instead of an equals in the "assignment" of `new_node->next`.

Third, in `printlist`, you should initialize `last` to `NULL` in case the list is empty; otherwise, you will attempt to walk the list backwards from an undefined starting (ending) point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for your pointers head and tail.

```
int main()

    {
        struct node *head;
        struct node *tail;
        head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));   //allocating memory to head
        tail = malloc(sizeof(struct node));   //allocating memory to tail
        head->data = 5;
        tail->data = 10;
        head->next = tail;
        head->prev = NULL;
        tail->next = NULL;
        insertAfter(head, 8);

        printf("\n Created DLL is: ");
        printlist(head);

        return 0;
    }
```

Also, never cast the return value of malloc, therefore change:

`struct node* new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

to

`struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

Comment: Or even `struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node)`

Comment: Why to 'never cast the return value of malloc'? The program works fine even if I do so.

Comment: [Do I cast the return value of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 0):

You want `new_node->next` to be the same as `new_node`?

if not, you'd better swap these two lines, in `InsertAfter`:

```
node->next = new_node;
new_node->next - node->next;
```